# is it possible add own app name in RPSystemBroadcastPickerView for screen share in google meet

Tags: ios, swift, rpsystembroadcastpickerview

I want to share screen even when app is in background. I implemented broadcast upload extension. Added the app group and bundle id in extension target. But on sharing my app is not showing in RPSystemBroadcastPickerView. it has photos and meet options. Deployment version is same in both targets and device version is greater than deployment version.PLS HELP!!